# How to remove a row from datagrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I populate a DataGrid from a CollectionViewSource. Each row has a delete button.
On delete i'm deleting a row from the DB.
My problem is that the DataGrids' UI doesn't update.
How do i clear the deleted row from the DataGrid?

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the underlying collection implements from INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and OnPropertyChanged is called when the row is deleted.

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) is a colelction that implements INotifyPropertyChanged so consider using that as an underlying collection object.

MSDN Remarks on [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

> CollectionViewSource is a proxy for a
>   CollectionView class, or a class
>   derived from CollectionView.
>   CollectionViewSource enables XAML code
>   to set the commonly used
>   CollectionView properties, passing
>   these settings to the underlying view.
>   CollectionViewSource has a View
>   property that holds the actual view
>   and a Source property that holds the
>   source collection.
>
> You can think of a collection view as
>   the layer on top of the binding source
>   collection that allows you to navigate
>   and display the collection based on
>   sort, filter, and group queries, all
>   without having to manipulate the
>   underlying source collection itself.
>   If the source collection implements
>   the INotifyCollectionChanged
>   interface, the changes raised by the
>   CollectionChanged event are propagated
>   to the views.
>
> Because views do not change the
>   underlying source collections, each
>   source collection can have multiple
>   views associated with it. For example,
>   you may have a collection of Task
>   objects. With the use of views, you
>   can display that same data in
>   different ways. For example, on the
>   left side of your page you may want to
>   show tasks sorted by priority, and on
>   the right side, grouped by area.
>
> For more information, see the Binding
>   to Collections section in the Data
>   Binding Overview.

Comment: Thanks!
Changing to ObservableCollection was what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

you should also Remove that row data from CollectionViewSource. or again laod the CollectionViewSource from database.

Thanks